# Oracle xml_dom.writeToClob does ignore the character set

Tags: oracle, plsql, xmldom

I'm trying to generate a xml file using oracle. After generating the xml using dbms_xmldom, it is stored in a CLOB and later written to a table.

The problem is that the character set ('UTF-8') is not included in the header even though it is specified using setCharset() procedure.

Following is the oracle script,

```
declare
  export_file_   CLOB ;     
  str_export_file_ xmldom.DOMDocument;
  main_node xmldom.DOMNode;
  root_node xmldom.DOMNode;
  root_elmt xmldom.DOMElement;

begin

    str_export_file_ := xmldom.newDOMDocument;
    xmldom.setVersion(str_export_file_, '1.0');
    xmldom.setCharset(str_export_file_ , 'UTF-8');
    main_node := xmldom.makeNode(str_export_file_);
    root_elmt := xmldom.createElement(str_export_file_,'TextTranslation');
    xmldom.setAttribute( root_elmt, 'version' ,'1.0');
    xmldom.setAttribute( root_elmt, 'language' ,'ja');
    xmldom.setAttribute( root_elmt, 'module' ,'DEMOAND');
    xmldom.setAttribute( root_elmt, 'type' ,'VC');
    root_node := xmldom.appendChild(main_node, xmldom.makeNode(root_elmt));

   export_file_ :=' ';
   xmldom.writeToClob( str_export_file_,export_file_,'UTF-8');

   dbms_output.put_line ( export_file_ ); 
end;
```

The output is ,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TextTranslation version="1.0" language="ja" module="DEMOAND" type="VC"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong so far. As a workaround you can use

```
export_file_ := REPLACE(
     export_file_
    ,'<?xml version="1.0"?>'
    ,'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'
);
```